# Activemq web console in Spring

Tags: spring, web, console, activemq-classic

I am creating an embedded ActiveMQ broker in Spring application like this:

```
@EnableJms
@Configuration
public class MqConfig {
    @Bean
    public BrokerService broker() throws Exception {
        BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
        broker.setBrokerName("ETL");
        broker.addConnector("tcp://localhost:61616");
        broker.start();
        return broker;
    }
}
```

How can I embed the ActiveMQ Admin Web console also in the same spring application? Searched the net for 2-3 hours, but found no useful answer. The only thing that ActiveMQ site mentions is this http://activemq.apache.org/web-console.html, however is not useful with Spring